# android custom view findviewId null and no visible

Tags: android, kotlin, custom-view, findviewbyid

I'm trying to use my own custom view inflated with layout.xml file. I use this view many times, but sometimes it doesn't show with preview in Android Studio. And when I get this custom view in Activity by 'findViewById' (In fact, I use Kotlin so I just writing Id directly.) it always returns null.
 I read so many questions about 'custom view findviewById returns null', until now I didn't find the answer. What am I wrong?

This is My Custom Class

```
class SubTitleBar(ctx:Context) : RelativeLayout(ctx) {

    private val mTitle:TextView
    private val mSideBtn:TextView

    constructor(ctx: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : this(ctx) {
        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SubTitleBar)
        setAttributeSet(typedArray)
    }

    constructor(ctx: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle:Int) : this(ctx, attrs) {
        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SubTitleBar, defStyle, 0)
        setAttributeSet(typedArray)
    }
    init {
        val infService = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE
        val inflater = ctx.getSystemService(infService) as LayoutInflater
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cv_subtitle,this,false)

        mTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.subtitle_title)
        mSideBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.subtitle_btn)

        addView(view)
}


    private fun setAttributeSet(typedArray: TypedArray) {

        val titleText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.SubTitleBar_title)
        mTitle.text = titleText

        val btnText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.SubTitleBar_btnText)

        if (btnText!= null && btnText.isNotEmpty()) {
            mSideBtn.text = btnText
        } else {
            mSideBtn.visibility = TextView.GONE
        }

        val showDivider = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.SubTitleBar_showDivider, false)

        if (showDivider) {
            subtitle_divider.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }


        typedArray.recycle()
    }

    fun setTitle(title:String) {
        mTitle.text = title
    }

    fun setSideButtonClickListener(listener: (View) -> Unit) = mSideBtn.setOnClickListener(listener)

}
```

And This is cv_subtitle.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="52dp"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle_title"
        style="@style/SubTitleNormal"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/contentStartPadding"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle_btn"
        style="@style/SubTitleSideBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/contentEndPadding"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/subtitle_divider"
        style="@style/PaddingDividerGray"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In Fragment layout resource file I use like this.

```
    <com.sample.harleyquinn.view.SubTitleBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/subTitleBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/my_apt_list_subtitle"
        app:title="apt"
        app:btnText="edit"
        />
```

In Fragment (or Activity) I try like this.

```
val subTitle = my_apt_list_subtitle
```

I try this too, but doesn't work.

```
val subTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.my_apt_list_subtitle)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the attributes, which includes the id to the super type. You have to change

```
class SubTitleBar(ctx:Context) : RelativeLayout(ctx) {
```

to

```
class SubTitleBar(ctx:Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : RelativeLayout(ctx, attrs) {
```

and change your other constructors accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Try to include the SubTitleBar in the cv_subtitle.xml

Comment: sorry I'm late-.. I want to inflate custom view with xml file. I can't understand your purpose with including SubTitleBar in cv_subtitle.xml file . Because cv_subtitle.xml is xml layout for SubTitleBar (my custom view).